# Linking R package vignettes

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is there any way I can include links between package vignettes in **R**? I know I can link between section, for example

```
# Section 1 {#section1}
My first section

# Section 2
A link to [Section 1](#section1)
```

But is there any way I can get a clickable link that will launch the HTML doucment of another vignette? Or is it just easier to give the code to launch it?

````
```r
vignette("my vignette", package = "myPackage")
```
````

Note I have generated all of my vignettes using `Rmarkdown` and `knitr`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, this is simple. Vignettes are all stored in the same directory, so you simply refer to the appropriate file name. The drat package [vignettes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eddelbuettel/drat/master/vignettes/DratForPackageAuthors.Rmd) have several examples of this. Here is a link from one vignette to the other:

```
This vignette deals with the first case: How to use
[drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) as a package author.  A
[companion vignette for package users](DratForPackageUsers.html) is available as well.
```

This will work on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drat/index.html) and on a user's machine.

You should also be able to link from vignettes to documentation, and vice versa, on a user's machine, knowing that vignettes are stored in `library/PKGNAME/doc/` and documentation is stored in: `library/PKGNAME/html/`.

Comment: Yep, works. Fantastic. Thanks very much - I was missing the `.html` which was why I couldn't get it to work myself.

Comment: I think you mean docs are stored in library/PKGNAME/html, right? I can link to a doc from a knitr html_vignette with [someFun](../html/someFun.html)

Comment: This shorter code in help instead of html works for me too: [someFun](../help/someFun)