# How to put a link to another vignette in the same R package in a vignette

Tags: r, r-markdown, bioconductor, vignette

I have a package on Bioconductor and I'm in the process of adding a second vignette to it.

I want to link the second vignette to the first vignette, as one vignette is on the general workflow of the package and the second is on fine parameter tuning, for more advanced users.

Is there a clean way to do it ?

The only related topic that I found is this one :
[best way to link to a vignette from manual in an R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963213/best-way-to-link-to-a-vignette-from-manual-in-an-r-package)

But it did not really helped me,

Thanks for your help,
Alexis

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34949337/2275286) answer may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing the vignettes in markdown, just link to the second vignette as you would link to any html file. Since all the vignettes are in the same directory, you don't need any file path info, just:  see here for more info