# Replacing the vignette with a new version

Tags: r, vignette

I submitted an R Package to CRAN a couple of months back which is currently available as a package. I submitted the vignette along with the package. Now I have an updated version of my vignette which I need to replace with the old vignette. How to proceed?

I checked in [How to put a link to another vignette in the same R package in a vignette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498760/how-to-put-a-link-to-another-vignette-in-the-same-r-package-in-a-vignette)

but that lacks clarity to what I'm looking for.

Please help. Thanks.

PS. I have a PDF file of the vignette

Comment: How was this PDF created? Are you using devtools and where exactly do you want to replace it?

Comment: If you want to replace the CRAN vignette, you'll need to submit a new release on CRAN

Comment: I have a completely different sort of a "paper" where I need to upload.